# Isolate no longer works since addition of eventReactive and observeEvent?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

Previously, I had built a shiny dashboard with chart outputs that worked just fine and looked like the following:

```
output$someName <- renderGvis({
  input$inputButton

  data <- isolate(myData(function here))
  donut <- gvisDonut({...})

  return(donut)
})
```

Since the addition of observeEvent and eventReactive, I've not been able to get it to work the same as before. Essentially, the output$someName is a chart that is dependent on multiple inputs, and each time the user clicks on the inputButton, I need renderGvis to re-evaluate. The function should NOT re-evaluate when any of the other inputs change, just when the button is pressed.

I've had some luck getting observeEvent to run on input$inputButton click, however, each time I change any of my input parameters, the query is quickly rerun without having to press the button. Any takers here?

More detailed below:

```
output$someName <- renderGvis({
  input$inputButton

  data <- isolate(dataGrabber({})) # function that takes input and returns data frame using RMySQL

  isolate(simpleChart(data = data)) # simpleChart is a function to produce a gvisCalendar chart.
```

Comment: have you tried isolating whatever the gvisDonut reactive is?

Comment: as in donut <- isolate(...)? Yep. Unsure if this makes any difference, but the gvisDonut actually comes form a custom function that outputs the gvisDonut.donut <- customFunction({code that produces gvisDonut}). I tried isolating the function, tried isolating things from inside the function, etc. I think the way that isolate() works has changed?

Comment: Is output$someName inside another reactive? like: createoutputs <- reactive({output$somename <- renderGvis(...)}). Also try isolating both the gvisDonut({}) and the return(isolate(donut))

Comment: Nope...not in a reactive. Updated with a little more detail. I think the problem is that I'm using two custom functions instead of calling the actual chart & RMySQL functions directly? I have one function that sits on top of RMySQL, and another that sits on top of gvisCalendarChart. (or gvisDonut, or gvisAnyChart). Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried changing the ignoreInit argument to TRUE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK...found an answer to this if anyone ever has this problem. The issue, which for some reason I had not encountered in the past, is that the isolate function now runs regardless of whether or not the value for actionButton is 0 or not. I believe in the past, it wouldn't run until actionButton had a value greater than 0.

The simple fix was:

```
output$someName <- renderGvis({
  input$inputButton
  if (input$inputButton == 0)
  return()

  isolate({ code to isolate})
})
```